# Adding ul li image on html5 canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas

I have three `li` tags within a `ul` tag, each of them containing an image within it. I have a `canvas` tag. I am trying to put the `ul` inside `canvas` but then, nothing is showing up. This is my code.

```
<canvas>
  <ul>
    <li><img src="1.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="2.jpg" /></li>
    <li><img src="13.jpg" /></li>
  </ul>
</canvas>
```

When I place the `ul` outside, everything is showing up. I want to display the whole `ul` within the `canvas`. Is it possible? If possible then how? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show a transparent canvas over the `ul`, or you want the `ul` to appear inside the canvas as rendered text? What function is the canvas actually serving?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images time to study.

Answer (score 1):

HTML elements cannot be placed inside of canvas elements (and be expected to be shown). They will be interpretted as text and be displayed if the browser does not support the canvas element

With that being said, you can layer the elements to where it is likely similar to the goal you're trying to achieve.

If you use the same dimensions, the same `top` & `left` position, and both have `position:absolute`, you can put the element you want on top after the other in the HTML. In the demo, I put the canvas after the `ul` so it is on top

```
ul, canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100px; height:100px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/caCLZ/1/)

Using the same technique, you can make one appear above the other by giving it a higher `z-index` value regardless of its position in the HTML. [**Demo using `z-index`**](http://jsfiddle.net/caCLZ/2/)

Comment: You could probably mention that you can't put any other elements *inside* the canvas tags as they will be ignored by browsers which support canvas (ref OP's example).

Comment: Updated as you suggested